# FFMpeg HLS output settings required for Approval by the Apple App Store

Tags: ffmpeg, appstore-approval, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I have looked all over, but I have not found a direct answer for my question so far.

What are the minimum required FFMpeg command line output and segmentation settings that will produce a minimum set of all the required HLS .m3u8 and .ts file combinations needed for Approval by the Apple App Store for a Video file played in an App?

Note there are older Q&As on here that were written before FFMpeg added native segmentation for HLS.  So I'm looking for 100% FFMpeg solution to output what Apple is looking for. I don't care about the input format for this answer as FFMpeg reads most any file we would want to use.

Note the correct answer should take into account the setting for maximum bandwidth requirments for the total stream and etc that Apple looks for.

I bet someone out there has already got this answered, maybe even running in some code but I want to see it posted to save the rest of us some time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The minimum is one video stream and one 64k audio-only stream, with h.264 and aac. That said, this is what I use, 180p+360p+480p+720p+1080p+64aac, just put together the parts you need.

I get videos of all sizes so my code pads or clips everything to 16:9, remove it if you don't need it.

Also, you need to generate the master m3u8 that points to the others.

[whatever] -> h.264 + AAC

```
ffmpeg -y -async 1 -vsync -1 -analyzeduration 999999999 -i INPUT.FILE
#180p -movflags faststart -keyint_min 30 -x264opts "keyint=30:min-keyint=30:no-scenecut" -g 30 -filter:v "scale=iw*min(320/iw\,180/ih):ih*min(320/iw\,180/ih), pad=320:180:(320-iw*min(320/iw\,180/ih))/2:(180-ih*min(320/iw\,180/ih))/2" -r:v 30 -s 320x180 -b:v 320k -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -c:a libfdk_aac -ac 2 -ar 48000 -b:a 64k OUTPUT-180.MP4
#360p -movflags faststart -keyint_min 30 -x264opts "keyint=30:min-keyint=30:no-scenecut" -g 30 -filter:v "scale=iw*min(640/iw\,360/ih):ih*min(640/iw\,360/ih), pad=640:360:(640-iw*min(640/iw\,360/ih))/2:(360-ih*min(640/iw\,360/ih))/2" -r:v 30 -s 640x360 -b:v 640k -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -c:a libfdk_aac -ac 2 -ar 48000 -b:a 96k OUTPUT-360.MP4
#480p -movflags faststart -keyint_min 30 -x264opts "keyint=30:min-keyint=30:no-scenecut" -g 30 -filter:v "scale=iw*min(854/iw\,480/ih):ih*min(854/iw\,480/ih), pad=854:480:(854-iw*min(854/iw\,480/ih))/2:(480-ih*min(854/iw\,854/ih))/2" -r:v 30 -s 854x480 -b:v 680k -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -c:a libfdk_aac -ac 2 -ar 48000 -b:a 96k OUTPUT-480.MP4
#720p -movflags faststart -keyint_min 30 -x264opts "keyint=30:min-keyint=30:no-scenecut" -g 30 -filter:v "scale=iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih):ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih), pad=1280:720:(1280-iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2:(720-ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih))/2" -r:v 30 -s 1280x720 -b:v 1280k -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -level 3.1 -c:a libfdk_aac -ac 2 -ar 48000 -b:a 128k OUTPUT-720.MP4
#1080p -movflags faststart -keyint_min 30 -x264opts "keyint=30:min-keyint=30:no-scenecut" -g 30 -filter:v "scale=iw*min(1920/iw\,1080/ih):ih*min(1920/iw\,1080/ih), pad=1920:1080:(1920-iw*min(1920/iw\,1080/ih))/2:(1080-ih*min(1920/iw\,1080/ih))/2" -r:v 30 -s 1920x1080 -b:v 1640k -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -level 4.0 -c:a libfdk_aac -ac 2 -ar 48000 -b:a 128k OUTPUT-1080.MP4
#aac -c:a libfdk_aac -ac 2 -ar 48000 -b:a 64k OUTPUT-AAC.AAC
```

MP4 -> TS

```
#180p ffmpeg -y -async 1 -vsync -1 -analyzeduration 999999999 -i OUTPUT-180.MP4 -codec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_list OUTPUT-180.M3U8 -segment_time 10 -segment_list_type m3u8 -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb SEGMENT-180%05d.TS
#360p ffmpeg -y -async 1 -vsync -1 -analyzeduration 999999999 -i OUTPUT-360.MP4 -codec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_list OUTPUT-360.M3U8 -segment_time 10 -segment_list_type m3u8 -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb SEGMENT-360%05d.TS
#480p ffmpeg -y -async 1 -vsync -1 -analyzeduration 999999999 -i OUTPUT-480.MP4 -codec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_list OUTPUT-480.M3U8 -segment_time 10 -segment_list_type m3u8 -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb SEGMENT-480%05d.TS
#720p ffmpeg -y -async 1 -vsync -1 -analyzeduration 999999999 -i OUTPUT-720.MP4 -codec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_list OUTPUT-720.M3U8 -segment_time 10 -segment_list_type m3u8 -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb SEGMENT-720%05d.TS
#1080p ffmpeg -y -async 1 -vsync -1 -analyzeduration 999999999 -i OUTPUT-1080.MP4 -codec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_list OUTPUT-1080.M3U8 -segment_time 10 -segment_list_type m3u8 -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb SEGMENT-1080%05d.TS
#aac ffmpeg -y -async 1 -vsync -1 -analyzeduration 999999999 -i OUTPUT-AAC.AAC -codec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_list OUTPUT-AAC.M3U8 -segment_time 10 -segment_list_type m3u8 -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb SEGMENT-AAC%05d.TS
```